# не записывается данные в процесс

Tags: linux, c

сделал для примера такую программу.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

int get_num ( ) {
        static int index = 0;
        static int size = sizeof ( a ) / sizeof ( int );
        if ( index >= size ) index = 0;
        int num = a[index++];
        num = 10;
        return num;
}

int main ( ) {
        int i = 0;
        printf ( "pid: %d\n", getpid ( ) );
        while ( 1 ) {
                int num = get_num ( );
                printf ( "i:%d\n", num );
                sleep ( 1 );
        }
}
```

я точно не помню, но вроде в секцию кода нельзя делать записи, но это я читал так давно, что могу ошибаться. я видел некоторые примеры, и вроде бы они подтверждают что записать в процесс можно, но можно ли записать в чужой процесс? в общем с помощью objdump я посмотрел адрес где `num = 10`. вот он.

`11d1:  c7 45 fc 0a 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0xa`

для этого я написал такую программу. и захотел заменить 10 на 11. но не выходит. пишет `ptrace poketext: Input/output error`
.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>

int main ( int argc, char **argv ) {
        if ( argc < 2 ) return -1;
        int pid = atoi ( argv[1] );

        int ret = ptrace ( PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, NULL, NULL );
        if ( ret == -1 ) perror ( "ptrace" );
        printf ( "ret: %d\n", ret );
        long addr = 0x00005555555551d4;
        long opcode = 0xb;
        ret = ptrace ( PTRACE_POKETEXT, pid, ( void * ) addr, ( void * ) opcode );
        if ( ret == -1 ) perror ( "ptrace poketext" );

        ptrace ( PTRACE_DETACH, pid, NULL, NULL );
}
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что это (`long addr = 0x00005555555551d4`) правильный адрес?

Comment: Заинтересовался и немного погуглил. Думаю, [эта статья в хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/473740/) и может быть [эти примеры от 2002 года](https://www.opennet.ru/base/dev/ptrace_guide.txt.html) заслуживают внимания

Comment: @avp насчёт адреса. я с помощью gdb отладчика несколько раз проверял программу. и каждый раз один и тот же адрес. но адрес там был `*1d1`, но мне надо было перейти сразу на значение третьего байта.

Comment: Мне кажется, вам все же нужно через /proc найти актуальные адреса, по которым загружена программа, когда вы делаете ptrace (может бытть они отличаются от тех, что вы видите, когда используете gdb)

Comment: @avp хорошо. посмотрю. спасибо за подсказку.